# Back navigation with bottom navigation view and navigation component

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation

I have a bottom navigation view with 3 entry points (fragments A, B and C), and each of them can move to other fragments (A->D, B->E, C->F). To navigate, I am using the architecture navigation component.
I want that when the user is in A, B or C and he presses the back button the app exits. If he is in D, E or F he should go to A, B or C respectively.

According to the documentation having the same ids in the menu and navigation graph is the way to set the view and navigation component up.

I know I can override the navigation and handle it myself to achieve what I want, or override the back button. But I would like to know if there is a way of achieving the desired behaviour without having to handle it manually (after all, that's the point of using the navigation component). Is there a way of doing this?

Also, is what I want to achieve the desired behaviour in material design with Android? It is my understanding that it is, but I could not find it in the material design documentation. I've tried several apps and I see different behaviours (twitter, maps and gmail don't exit the app, but tasks or keep do), so I suppose that both behaviours are acceptable.

Comment: The [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination) make it clear that you should always exit out of the start destination of your graph (for example, your A screen). Are you specifically asking how to *not* follow the Principles of Navigation?

Comment: Well, in this case we are talking about several screens at the same root level, so that is why I want them all to exit. And as I mentioned, tasks (when changing from one list to another) and keep (changing from tasks to reminders) -google apps- do exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination) were specifically built by the Material and Android UX teams at Google as the way apps should be designed so as to prevent confusion on what the back button will do:

> This [start] destination is also the last screen the user sees when they return to the launcher after pressing the Back button.

This ensures that users know that the back button won't kick them out of the app when on any other screen of your app. Conversely, that start destination serves as a sign post to the user that pressing the system back button *will* kick them back to the launcher.

So it is absolutely expected that, when using the `NavigationUI` helpers, that you will always exit through the start destination of your graph (i.e., your `A` screen).

Navigation has a separate concept, called [top level destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration), which controls only whether the Up arrow on the app bar is displayed. This allows multiple top level destinations (such as your A, B, and C) to appear on the same hierarchical level from the user's point of view while still matching the system back Principles of exiting through the start destination.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, to make sure I understand it properly, the behaviour implemented in Tasks and Keep is against the Principles of Navigation? In tasks if you change from one list to another and press back you exit the app. And in keep if you go from notes to reminders and press back you exit de app.

Comment: Personally, taking Google apps as some sort of shining example is generally a misguided idea (they're all independent teams with independent sets of goals and priorities). Tasks' start destination (their 'Fragment A') is a list of tasks. Replacing one instance of A with another instance still means they exit the app through their start destination (and is a totally separate case from bottom nav, your use case). Keep *does* have a strong start destination in their Notes screen, so being consistent between Reminders, Archive, and other Labels seems like good feedback for them.